# How to give (already purchased) Android app to customer as a gift?

Tags: android, google-play, google-checkout, android-lvl

Yes, SO, I know, it's not a "programmer's" question:) But customers sometimes help us (devs) with our code, so we (devs) shold be grateful. I think answer to my question will be useful for all fellow android devs.

User has purchased my app. Refund period (15min) is over of course. Now I'd like to return money to him as a gift, because he helped me in testing a little.

If I refund the entire order in Checkout->Orders will user keep my app 'purchased'? I mean will he be able to uninstall and install it again from GooglePlay->MyApps and will app be marked "purchased"? Will Google LVL accept him to run the app?

I've done such refunds before, but then they called it "Android Market", and refund was 12h, and there were no LVL. Maybe somebody know another way to make a small gift using Google Play?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now generate and distribute promo codes for your app or game to current and new users on Google Play.

Under the **Promotions** tab in the Google Play Developer Console, you can set up promo codes for your apps, games, and in-app products to distribute in your own marketing campaigns (up to 500 codes per app, per quarter):

1. Go to your Google Play Developer Console, select your app.
2. Select **Promotions > Add new promotion**.
3. Follow the on-screen instructions (promotion name, start and end dates, promotion type, number of promo codes you want to create).
4. Select **Create**, select the **download** link.
   Your codes will download to a CSV file. To share with users, you can print the codes or send a deep link allowing users to redeem the codes via email or a notification within your app.

References: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/create-promo-codes-for-your-apps-and-in.html

Answer (score 6):

Google play has no gifting implemented currently.

Refunding the purchase will automatically uninstall the app from the user's device, and LVL will not accept him as a registered user if he sideloads it.

Comment: Here's the official answer from Google: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2850372?hl=en

Comment: Is this verified? I was under the impression that when I refund an order in Checkout/Wallet the buyer just gets the money and keeps the app... How am I suppose to give my app for free to users that help translate or so?... :(

Comment: @Peterdk You can't. When you refund the purchase, they stop receiving updates and the app is usually automatically uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

You can't give him a gift. There's no gift concept implemented in Google Play.

Comment: You could give them your phone (and google username and password) ;)

Answer (score 1):

All we can do at this time is refund a purchase through the Google Wallet merchant account, **after 48 hours** (when the customer-initiated refund period expires, which may be different in the future).

If they get a refund from Google it will uninstall the app and remove their access.

If you do it personally from your Wallet merchant account, after 48 hours (or whenever the end is of the customer-initiated refund period), they still get to keep the app and get updates.

Comment: "they still get to keep the app and get updates." is there any source from Google that confirms this, or have you just realized this by experience?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2479637

I've never done it and it could have been changed to revoke the license to use the app now.  I think there are a few options, and you get to choose if the license is revoked or not.  I think there is at least an option to pay them any amount from your account without it being connected to the app, so you could pay them back what they paid you without it being considered a refund for the app.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, but have you thought about asking the customer in question to purchase the app, and then sending him/her the money via PayPal or something? Also, what if *you* initiate the refund process? In that case, I wouldn't expect the app to be uninstalled, as the user didn't agree to an uninstall.

Comment: If I initiate refund process GP will remove app from user's device. Paypal - there is a transfer fee, so if we want to give our app as a gift we have to pay.

Comment: Wouldn't the user have to agree to it though? What if the user wants to keep using the app, even if it means not getting a refund? Also who downvoted me and why?

Comment: It's not actually an answer. You don't even know the subject, so I think that's why your answer is downvoted. About the app - yes, it will just disappear from the device without warning.

Comment: The second part about the developer initiating the refund process wasn't really part of the answer. The real answer was suggesting he use PayPal, and he explained why that wouldn't work for him. The reason I assumed the app wouldn't be uninstalled if the developer initiated the refund process is what if the user doesn't want the app uninstalled? Seriously: what if a developer doesn't want people to use their app anymore, so he/she refunds everyone (uninstalling the app) and takes it off the market? How would you defend yourself from that? Is there a way to opt out of refunds? Does it ask you?